# RxSwift emit starting value with time interval and modify it

Tags: swift, timer, observable, rx-swift

I need to decrease input value with every second, and print it. 
When value reaches 0, then it becomes 100, and decreasing process repeats, and again.

**For example:**

```
Given value: 
-> 234
Timer starts decreasing with every second
 -> 233
 -> 232 
...
 -> 1
 -> 0 and the whole process repeats,

but starts with value 100 
(and again decreasing, reaches 0, starting from 100)
```

I know how to use timer in Rx, but how to connect it with described case?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

How about creating an observable from the 1 second interval and another observable from the sequence of numbers and then zipping them together?  Like this:

```
let interval = Observable<Int>.interval(1, scheduler: MainScheduler.instance)
let startValue1 = 234
let startValue2 = 100

let range1 = Observable
    .range(start: 0, count: startValue1 + 1)
    .map { startValue1 - $0 }

let range2 = Observable
    .range(start: 0, count: startValue2 + 1)
    .map { startValue2 - $0 }
    .repeatWithBehavior(.immediate(maxCount: .max))
    .subscribeOn(SerialDispatchQueueScheduler(qos: .background))

Observable.zip(
    interval,
    range1.concat(range2))
    .subscribe(onNext : { (_, remainingTime) in
        print("\(remainingTime)")
    })
```

It's a bit verbose but it avoids any mutable state.  HTH

Comment: That is something which I was looking for, thanks :)

Answer (score 3):

You just need one variable with initial value like below:

```
var start = 234

func startTimer() {
     _ = Observable<Int>
          .timer(0, period: 1, scheduler: MainScheduler.instance)
          .subscribe(onNext: { _ in
              self.start -= 1
              if self.start <= 0 {
                  self.start = 100
              }
              print("Timer value>>>> : ",self.start)
          })
}
```